# can cross contract calls be done across different polkadot chains?

Tags: polkadot, ink, phala

I have two smart contracts, one for `off-chain` computations (Phat Contracts) and the other from Ink which will be deployed on the `Astar network`. I want to access data from the phat contracts, how do I do this? Is this even possible?